# How to set up letsencrypt with a S3 backed static website?

Tags: https, amazon-aws

I am creating a personal website which will have a blog and host various files that I create, some of which might be large, such as photographs.

- I plan to host it with AWS Cloudfront, backed by S3. There are many reasons to do this; having 1TB of monthly free traffic with world-class CDN response time is a bit of a no brainer.
- I own my domain, it's with a domain registrar and I have access to change its DNS records. I can point this toward cloudfront to get things connected up.

I need to generate SSL certs for my domain. But since I am setting up to host with S3 and Cloudfront, neither of which work like bona fide servers under my control, I have no way to run letsencrypt.

What's the most straightforward path toward my goal? Are there steps in here that have problematic security posture?

- Create a temporary ec2 or lightsail instance, configure DNS at my registrar control panel to point to its elastic IP, use letsencrypt there to generate certs, transfer them to cloudfront distribution, shut down instance, point DNS at my cloudfront distribution
- Create a port 443 forward (and maybe any other ports needed for ACME) in my home router to my computer to some port(s), configure DNS at my registrar control panel to point to my home dynamic IP, run letsencrypt on my computer, transfer the certs into cloudfront distribution, point DNS at cloudfront distribution
- transfer DNS(/domain? not too sure how this works) into Route 53, wire DNS up with ec2/lightsail instance, run letsencrypt, transfer certs to cloudfront distribution, wire DNS over to cloudfront distribution

Is there a tool that AWS provides that can streamline this process?

It seems like if I want to use a free cert via letsencrypt that requires regular renewal, this requires a service that stays up or comes up often enough to implement that and is somewhat at odds with the use of s3 to back the site.

Comment: It looks like I've overthunk this. Looks like what I was wishing for exists. I'll be following https://medium.com/@itsmattburgess/hosting-a-https-website-using-aws-s3-and-cloudfront-ee6521df03b9 and if it works for me i'll convert it into the answer

Comment: Plot thickens. Reading about cloudflare they really have no bandwidth limit at all. And maybe I don't want to hand the keys to Amazon. Food for thought...

Comment: Gonna follow this actually https://miketabor.com/how-to-host-a-static-website-using-aws-s3-and-cloudflare/

Comment: Is your DNS hosted in AWS Route 53?  If so, have you looked into using a DNS challenge?  Certbot has a plugin for it: https://certbot-dns-route53.readthedocs.io/en/stable/  I use it and it works quite well.  Then you don't have to do any of the mapping to your home computer that you were proposing.

Comment: Well I ended up going with Cloudflare, but am keeping the static resources backed by S3 for the time being. It does work well and will be free for even more traffic than cloudfront, plus it seems like I have just as much flexibility when it comes to DNS because Cloudflare is a replacement for both cloudfront and route53. I was also put off by per-request pricing that exists on route53, I am pretty sure it means that if traffic ever spikes significantly I will be paying a LOT more if using the AWS flavor of services.